# No me Muestra Menu(item) en ToolBar Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy agregando toolbar a una aplicación android, pero estoy teniendo problemas ya que no me muestra el menu(los item) en la toolbar, si me muestra la toolbar en el layout pero no me muestra el menu ya sobrescribi el metodo onCreateOptionsMenu y nada no me muestra el menu solo la toolbar.

mi xml del toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:title="App">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Asi la estoy incluyendo en la layout que la quiero mostrar

```
<include android:id="@+id/appbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

Este es mi menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Acerca"
        android:title="Acerca de" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Salir"
        android:title="Salir" />
</menu>
```

Y luego en la clase para incluir el toolbar y menu hago esto

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);


        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    //agrego menu a toolbar

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menutoolbar,menu );
        return  true;
    }

}
```

Como ven estoy sobreescribiendo el onCreateOptionsMenu pero no me muestra el menu, si me muestra el toolbar pero el menu no.

Que podria estar malo del codigo

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente tu menu no puede mostrarse por los elementos que se muestran en el Toolbar, te sugiero agregar la propiedad `app:showAsAction="always"` a los items del menú:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Acerca"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="Acerca de" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Salir"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="Salir" />
</menu>
```

pero **no olvides inflar el `menu` en el `Toolbar`**, esto seríar el problema principal:

```
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ...
    ...
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_manu);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me marca error toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_manu);   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.inflateMenu(int)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Pude usar tu codigo en un proyecto nuevo, la diferencia es que actualmente se usa ya androidx

**En el caso del del toolbar xml**

El unico cambio seria el tema del androidx

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

  </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Luego el código es el mismo al que tienes implementado

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Toolbar toolbar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
   }
}
```

**Resultado**

[image: Resultado]

Comment: utilizas alguna dependencia para usar android x porque me marca error aca setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: En realidad solo tienes que actualizar  a la ultima versión que te indica el IDE, que en este caso me parece que esta en la 3.5; como te comente en el post actualmente se usa androidx en algunos casos y tu gradle  ya estará usando las dependencias androidx automáticamente una ves que crees un nuevo proyecto.

Comment: lo que sucede es que estoy implementado el toolbar en un proyecto ya existente que no implementa android x porque me marca error.

Comment: Entiendo, voy a probar tu código en la versión correspondiente

Comment: @eduardoflores replique tu código en la versión correspondiente y si funciona, me muestra el menú  como en la imagen que te muestro en el post, yo te sugiero que revises  la librería que usas en tu loginActivity ya que deberia  ser: **import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar**; podrías estar importando esta librería que es incorrecta: **import android.widget.Toolbar**.